# How do I unlink my computer from a github account?

Tags: macos, git, github

I've been able to push with the mac GitHub app to a GitHub repo, but I'm trying to use the command line now and I see this error:

```
remote: Permission to bfred-it/test.git denied to wildlifela.
```

wildlifela is a company account that I used recently on a different project, I think I only [added my SSH key to that account.](https://github.com/settings/ssh)

The problem is that even after removing my key from that account (wildlifela), my account (bfred-it), the RSA keys from my computer (with `ssh-add -D`) and emptying the ~/.ssh folder, I still get that error.

It doesn't seem to be a repo issue: I just created a repo on GitHub.com, cloned it to my desktop, created a commit and `git push origin master` still produces that error.

After following the [Generating SSH Keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) procedure, `ssh -T git@github.com` authenticates me as bfred-it, but I still can't push as bfred-it.

What can I do?
(OSX 10.9)

Comment: I always create an SSH configuration (`~/.ssh/config`) for each repo/computer I use with SSH.  I then use the configuration name, rather than "github.com" in the remote URL and this also allow an explicit public/private keypair to be specified.  However I have found that this doesn't play nice with Xcode so I use `https://` rather than `ssh://` more recently.

Answer (score 0):

I *worked around* this issue by using a different version of git.

Instead of using OS X's git I'm now using homebrew's git and it's working correctly.

If anyone has any insights as to what was happening, please share.

Answer (score 0):

> although i removed the ssh keys and the git config files from the OS, it just won't let me clone/pull/push to repositories

1. Check that the repo is indeed owned by you (for pushing to it)
2. There always is the option of using https url (with GitHub username/password)
3. removing the ssh key might not be enough, you also have the ~/.ssh/config file.

As  mentioned in the comment, it can depend on your version of Git and on your OS (Windows, Mac or Linux).

Comment: Hi, the issue is that i linked to my macbook pro the github account of my sister with the ssh method, and since that i couldn't use any of my repos because it never gave me the chance again to complete user and password, instead it tried automatically to access all repos with my sister's account.

One thing to note is that all these repos were cloned via https, not ssh.
The https clone mechanism wouldn't work either
I removed all files at ~/.ssh/ and regenerated a new global priv and pub key

Comment: @HeberLZ I confirm that is the repos are cloned with https, no amount of ssh fiddling will change a thing. Can you try and uninstall GitHub for Mac, and reinstall it, to see if it gives you the chance to specify who you are?

Comment: I actually fixed it for the moment by configuring by SSH my own account after deleting everything on ~/.ssh/ and cloning via SSH, but if i try to clone something by https it still tries to use by default my sister's account without asking for a username/password

I don't recall when i installed git CLI and by which method but i'll try to fully reinstall it to check if that fixes this situation

Comment: @HeberLZ I confirm that https url will ignore your ssh settings;

Comment: Then probably besides the ssh config there is something else that just overrides the git command line interface user configuration because it just won't prompt a username/password via https, but don't know how to undo it, already deleted all git config files at ~/.git_config and alike :( Just in case i didn't say it before, this issue affects not only the all visual applications like the github one or smartgit but also the git command line interface

Comment: @HeberLZ Are you using a GUI like GitHub for Mac?

Comment: Yes, i used GitHub for Mac for a while, then uninstalled it and now i'm using Smartgit

Comment: @HeberLZ there must be a credential helper that feeds the password then

Comment: You are a genius! i googled credential helper (didn't know they even existed) and was able to successfully remove it! https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/